# Get all entities where the string array property contains the input string (MikroOrm + TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

I'm trying to make a MikroOrm query in Typescript that gets all Movies which belong to a specified inputGenre. Each Movie has not one, but an array of genres associated to it. So if I have the following movies:

```
"Titanic" -> ["romance", "drama"]
"The Godfather" -> ["crime", "drama"]
"The Dark Knight" -> ["action", "crime", "drama"]
```

and I'm searching for all "crime" movies, I'm expecting to fetch "The Godfather" and "The Dark Knight". Here's how the Movie is defined:

```
@Entity()
export class Movie {
  @PrimaryKey({ type: 'number' })
  id: number;

  @Property({ type: ArrayType })
  genreList: string[] = [];
}
```

I've tried the below code, but it returns only the movies that have exactly one genre, equal to inputGenre

```
queryBuilder.where({ genreList: { $contains: [inputGenre] } });
```

What am I missing?